# Can we make the accepted answer check mark greener?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Can we make it greener, or make the colour of the voting button a different colour entirely?

I thought I had seen an accepted answer on question because my down vote blue is not that far off from the accepted blueish green. On other stack exchange site, the accepted answer colour is very different from the voting colours. On The Workplace SE, it just kind of blends in with everything else.

Comment: I'm color deficient at that end of the spectrum, and I can see it alright.  Maybe if you adjust your contrast?

Comment: I think we could also make the arrow on the downvote button less similar to the check mark.

Comment: Even circles for voting and squares for accepted answers (or vise versa) would be an improvement

Comment: @RichardU I think OP is saying that the down vote and checkmark look too much alike. I think it looks fine, but I don't have any color vision problems.

Comment: I don't have any vision problems, but they are very similar. When I am skimming and scrolling around it can be hard to tell until I stop and look. They are of a similar colour and in a similar placement

Comment: seems related: [The many shades of green](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351530/839601) at MSO

Comment: To be honest, you can even just ignore both the colour and the symbol and work off the placement. The up/down votes are always next to the score and the Acceptance check is clearly placed separately from those. I don't see how this is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I really don't think this is a major issue.**

While I do agree that the checkmark and downvote look somewhat similar similar, I think the only way you could confuse them is if you scroll past without actually stopping to look at the answer. An accepted answer is always listed first among the answers, unless the page has been updated while you are viewing it. The only way you should confuse a downvote for an accept is if you have downvoted the first answer. Confusing an accept for a downvote is more likely, though if like me you sort answers by votes, I would remember if I downvoted the highest voted answer.

In either case, any possible harm that might occur from confusing the two should immediately be cleared up by anything more than a passing glance. While the two symbols might appear similar, the situations in which they could be confused are rare and *very* easily cleared up. **I don't think any action needs to be taken.**

Comment: Accepted answer are not always at the top, I've noticed a few exceptions. I think mostly if you accept your own answer, but it has a bad score.

Comment: @Erik Yeah, I wasn't completely sure that was always the case, but when I tested it out on a few questions with different sort methods, I could only get the accepted answer first.